# Insert date string to datetime2 in TSQL insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, datetime-format, datetime2

I need to insert a date string as DATETIME2 in the QUEUE table in Microsoft Sql Server.

DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "QUEUE" (
    ID  INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    TEAMID  VARCHAR(550) ,
    STATUS  VARCHAR(50) ,
    MSG VARCHAR(50) ,
    TIME    DATETIME2,
    ERROR   VARCHAR(10) ,
);

INSERT INTO QUEUE VALUES(2,'c33','ok','FoundID',CONVERT('Tue Sep 09 12:18:52 2014' AS DateTime2),'OK');
```

The value 'Tue Sep 09 12:18:52 2014' should be converted as datetime2 format like 2014-09-09 12:18:52.000000 and should be inserted.

I tried CAST and COVERT but it fails.

Comment: CONVERT('some string' AS DateTime2) is not valid syntax.  Please google and learn about the CONVERT() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out the syntax with the convert is a little off. The syntax should be like below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'Sep 09 12:18:52 2014')
```

Answer (score 0):

Dane's conversion works, but if the date is being passed as a field or variable, which includes a 3 letter day of the week at the beginning (like your example), it seems to still fail.  Assuming the first 4 characters are always the day of the week and a space, you could tweak Dane's example using RIGHT and LEN.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT('Tue Sep 09 12:18:52 2014',LEN('Tue Sep 09 12:18:52 2014')-4))
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim LaVenice .. Ur answer was right to the point . This was the one i was searching for.  The string conversion of the day was causing the problem.